# select2 multiple, no funciona al obtener los datos y enviarlos por ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Este es el codigo de como cargo el select2 multiple.

```
<select class="form-control select2_demo_1 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Programas" style="width: 100%;" name="softwares[]  id=" softwares[]"="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="20">AdobePDF</option>
<option value="5">AI</option>
<option value="2">Antivirus</option>
<option value="11">Brackets</option>
<option value="6">CorelDraw</option>
<option value="19">M.Office2007</option>
<option value="15">M.Office2010</option>
<option value="1">M.Office2013</option>
<option value="12">M.Office2016</option>
<option value="16">Nero</option>
<option value="4">Photoshop</option>
<option value="9">PremierPro</option>
<option value="18">Sadmun</option>
<option value="3">SonyVegas</option>
<option value="17">Wunderlist</option>
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hasta aquí cargo los datos con el múltiple, todo bien sin problemas.

Pero el verdadero problema este, no se como leer con los datos con javascript y postearlos con ajax.

```
 var softwares = $('#softwares').find(':selected');
    var softwares_txt = JSON.stringify(softwares ); 
    console.log('Selected IDs: ' + softwares_txt);


            $.ajax({
            url:"/sim/libs/ajax/computoNuevo.php",
            type: 'post',
            data: { 'softwares_txt':softwares_txt  },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.success==true){
                    $('#modalAgregarComputo').modal('hide');
                    tablaComputo.ajax.reload();
                    toastr.success('Equipo de computo agregado');
                    btnGcomputo.ladda('stop');
                }else{

                    toastr.error('Registro no guardado');
                    btnGcomputo.ladda('stop');

                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                toastr.error('Error no identificado');
                btnGcomputo.ladda('stop');
            }   

        })
```

y en el archivo donde se hace el post tengo esto

```
if( isset($_POST['softwares_txt'])) {echo $_POST["softwares_txt"];}
```

Alguien puede ayudarme a ver mi error,  ya que la variable  $_POST["softwares_txt"] no trae mas que errores.

muchas gracias.

Comment: Verifica con Chrome DevTools que ocurre en la pestaña network, es decir, en tú aplicación presiona F12, ves a pestaña network, F5 y observa la petición que realiza.. es posible que no te llegue dandote un 404 ?
Igual forma que haces stringify en softwares_txt hazlo en el data: de la petición ;)

Comment: ¿En qué parte de tu código obtienes los elementos seleccionados? Debería ser una línea arriba de ´$.ajax({´ ...

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño

me da indefinido o  si uso otra opción para tomar los datos me da object object


Según yo acá @Triby , pero es la primera vez que uso todo esto combinado y no se si este bien la sintaxis


```var softwares = $('#softwares').find(':selected');
var softwares_txt = JSON.stringify(softwares ); 
console.log('Selected IDs: ' + softwares_txt); ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con jquery-3.4.1.min.js

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: '/sim/libs/ajax/computoNuevo.php' , 
 method: 'POST',
 data: { 'softwares_txt':softwares_txt  }
}).done(function({success}){
      if ( success ) {
          $('#modalAgregarComputo').modal('hide');
          tablaComputo.ajax.reload();
          toastr.success('Equipo de computo agregado');
          btnGcomputo.ladda('stop');
      } else {
          toastr.error('Registro no guardado');
          btnGcomputo.ladda('stop');
      }
}).fail(function(jqXHR){
      toastr.error('Error no identificado');
      btnGcomputo.ladda('stop');
});
```

Doy por hecho que en plugin de Datatable tiene asignado un ajax referente a la URL que devuelve todos los registro de computos.

Verifica la petición se realiza correctamente con un 200:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es lo que no, se como hacerlo, por lo cual el post no trae nada.

Doy por hecho que en plugin de Datatable tiene asignado un ajax referente a la URL que devuelve todos los registro de computos.

gracias por responder @Joel

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax